# Способ обновления поля в БД (или как заменить функционал триггера)

Tags: алгоритм, mysql

День добрый, господа ! У меня есть вот такая задача, прошу поделиться советами. Спасибо заранее всем.
Итак, есть 3 таблицы.

- *Первая таблица*, это основная таблица
     данных, каждый день туда заносятся
     заявки .
- *Вторая*, это временная таблица, туда
     заносятся записи с первой таблицы,
     но только для текущего дня. Ну,
     заявки поступившиеся на сегодняшний
     день. Обновляется кроном каждые 5 минут.
- *Третья*, это как бы архивный вариант
     второй таблицы: каждый день, ночью,
     скажем в 23 ч 33 м (заявки
     принимаются до 21-00), все что было на сегодняшний день в первой таблице, архивируются в эту таблицу.

Теперь требования :

1) В первой таблице есть поле "комментарий", это не должно быть во второй таблице.

2) Во второй таблице(промежуточной) есть тоже поле "комментарий", это не должно быть в первой таблице.

3) В третьей таблице должно быть "комментарий" и первой, и второй таблицы.

Без проблем, если бы надо было только на сегодняшний день сделать архив заявок, пожалуйста, запускаю процедуру и все, все счастливы.

Есть один НО. В первой таблице комментарий может быть отредактирован когда угодно. И это тоже должен отражаться в третьей таблице. А в третью таблицу я заполняю каждый ночь и все. Как мне сделать, чтобы поле комментарий1 первой и комментарий1 третьей были абсолютно одинаковыми ?

***PS: использование триггера исключено.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вам помогут триггеры http://habrahabr.ru/post/37693/
надо создать триггер на обновление записи первой таблицы и прописать туда обновление третьей

Comment: я вот тоже подумал над этим, при обновлений первой, тоже обновить соответствующую запись в третьей таблице. Но триггера исключено..

Comment: а почему триггеры исключены?

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER `update_tab1` before update ON `tab1`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   UPDATE tab3 SET cooment1=OLD.comment WHERE tab3.id = OLD.id;
END;

Comment: это биллинговая система, при следующем обновлений системы автоматом, там все триггера, касающиеся системных таблиц стираются, т.е удаляются. Вот это и не гуд...Надо будет заново писать триггер.

Comment: А разве написать скрипт по созданию всех нужных триггеров и потом его выполнять после каждого обновления такая уж проблема?